# Using boolean mask in Python array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand how a boolean mask is used on an array in Python.  In the example below, the Python function successfully touches all the elements of the color_select array. How does it do that since the code looks like it only indexes the 0th or 1st element of color_select?

```
def color_thresh(img, thresh=(50, 50, 50)):
    color_select = np.zeros_like(img[:,:,0])
    above_thresh = (img[:,:,0] > thresh[0]) \
                 & (img[:,:,1] > thresh[1]) \
                 & (img[:,:,2] > thresh[2])
    color_select[above_thresh] = 1
    return color_select
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the `:` character specifies a range to index within an iterable. If no parameters are given (e.g. `list[:]`), then python reads this as "operate on the entire list".

In your code, it seems like `img` is a 3-dimensional array. For example, `img[:,:,0] > thresh[0]` says "take all of X and Y in the first level of Z, and check that it's greater than the first element of the set `thresh`". If `img` only has 3 "z-layers", then this code touches all elements of all 3 layers.

Comment: Ok, but it seems like above_thresh will only receive 1 or 0. How then can any element other than the 0th or 1st of color_select be set to 1?

Comment: So this is another subtlety of python arrays (specifically, it looks like you're using numpy). `img[:,:,0] > thresh[0]` won't return a single value, but rather an array of boolean values. This boolean array will have the same shape as `img` (I believe). `above_thresh` then becomes a 3 layer boolean mask, which then gets applied to `color_select` (`color_select[above_thresh] = 1` means "set `color_select` to `1` in all places where `above_thresh` is true).